# Bulk product upload in Google Business Profile

Tags: csv, bulk, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I have 1000 products in a csv file.

Is there any way to upload this in bulk to Google Business Profile for my site?

I tried connecting with my Google Merchant Center account and activating Google Free Product Listing program and it didn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated